# Variable in the url, xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I need to insert a variable in the URL
Exmp: `http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario= LALBELTEXT`

I have this code:

```
//creo una costante di tipo NSURL
let url = NSURL(string: "http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=IOS")

//creo una richiesta di accesso a quello specifico indirizzo
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
myWebView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Please be aware this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so I removed that tag. Also what do the comments say in english? This is an english speaking site.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the url as a string first:

```
    var URLstring = "http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=\(labeltext.text)"
    var theURL = NSURL(string: URLstring)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hi, have test but have error: Use of unresolved identify 'url'

Comment: is labeltext a UILabel?

Comment: is this @IBOutlet var txtUsername : UITextField!

Comment: @Messina ok, so put txtUsername.text instead of labeltext.text

Comment: var URLstring = "http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=\(txtUsername.text)"
            var theURL = NSURL(string: URLstring)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!)
            myWebView.loadRequest(request)
THis?

Comment: Have this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value , and sub code 0x0

Comment: Which variable is causing the crash?

Comment: this is code: 
        } else {
            self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString
            
            var URLstring = "http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=\(usernameLabel.text)"
            var theURL = NSURL(string: URLstring)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!)
            myWebView.loadRequest(request)

Comment: Have BREAKPOINT code xcx arm , sub code =0xe7ffdefe

Comment: use `} else { self.usernameLabel?.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString var URLstring = "http://www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=(usernameLabel.text)" var theURL = NSURL(string: URLstring) let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!) myWebView.loadRequest(request)`

Comment: URLs should not contain spaces. You had space before www.sito.com

Comment: var URLstring = "http://www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=(usernameLabel.text)"
            var theURL = NSURL(string: URLstring)
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: theURL!)
            myWebView.loadRequest(request)
This now work but not have variable username

Comment: So, check why you don't have that variable :)

Comment: If use this var URLstring = "http:// www.sito.com/frasi/ip.php?destinatario=\(label.text)" not work